# Get an image from drawables and show it in an ImageView

Tags: android

I am developing a recipe application.
Every recipe has 2 attributes.
One is an image.

I want to get the image from drawables and show it in an ImageView.

This is giving me an error.
Is there any other way to do that?

```
public Recipe(String name,int id){
   this.name=name; 
  this.image=  this.getResources().getDrawable(id);//error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `image` is an `ImageView` object, you should use [`ImageView.setImageDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29). Like this:

```
this.image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming image an ImageView object

```
image.setImageResource(id);
```